# CSS align vertical at bottom and center

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I found lots of solution but none that worked for me.
In the following markup the text "lorem ipsum example" should be aligned at the bottom and centered. I can't seem to figure it out!

```css
#box {
  background:#6CCB61 
 }
 .wrapper div {
  height: 240px;
        width:100%;
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
 }
 #boxGreen span {
  vertical-align: bottom;
 }

 .wrapper {
  width:auto;  
  margin: 0 10px;
 }
 #boxGreen {
  width:100%; 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">        
        <div id="box">
         <span>Lorem Ipsum Example</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
#box {
    background:#6CCB61;
    position: relative;
}

#box span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/veefmgna/